# Result set closed exception when trying to read a pdf file from sqlite table

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to read a pdf file that has been stored in a table on SQLite database. when I run the Code it says ' Resultset is closed'.

```
public void syllabusAttach(){
    String selectSQL = "SELECT Image_Reg FROM "+getRegulation()+" WHERE SubjectCode="+getSubCode()+"";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = connect();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);

        // write binary stream into file

            InputStream is =rs.getBinaryStream("Image_Reg");
            File file = new File("syllabus_"+getRegulation()+".pdf");
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            System.out.println("Writing BLOB to file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] content = new byte[1024];
            int size = 0;
            while((size = is.read(content)) !=-1){
                os.write(content,0,size);
            }



    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}


write binary stream into file
            File file = new File("syllabus_"+getRegulation()+".pdf");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        System.out.println("Writing BLOB to file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("Image_Reg");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer);
            }
        }
```

When I did the above changes to the code, I could see that the files are being generated but when I open them it says "this file cannot be opened"

Answer (score 0):

I found that the getSubCode() in the SQl query is not returning a the desired string which is leading to the error.